# AWS EKS with Fargate pod status pending due to PersistentVolumeClaim not found

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have deployed EKS cluster with Fargate and alb-ingress-access using the following command:

```
eksctl create cluster --name fargate-cluster --version 1.17 --region us-east-2 --fargate --alb-ingress-access
```

A Fargate namespace has also been created.

The application being deployed has four containers namely mysql, nginx, redis and web.

The YAML files have been applied to the correct namespace.

The issue I am having is that after applying the YAML files when I get the pods status I the following status:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
flipkicks     flipkicksdb-7669b44bbb-xww26      0/1     Pending   0          112m
flipkicks     flipkicksredis-74bbf9bd8c-p59hb   1/1     Running   0          112m
flipkicks     nginx-5b46fd5977-9d8wk            0/1     Pending   0          112m
flipkicks     web-56666f5d8-64w4d               1/1     Running   0          112m
```

MySQL and Nginx pods go into pending status. The deployment YAML for both have the following volumeMounts values:

MYSQL

```
volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          name: mysql-db
```

NGINX

```
volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/etc/nginx/conf.d"
          name: nginx-conf
        - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
          name: admin-panel
```

The output from the events part of the kubectl describe command for both pods is:

MYSQL

```
Events:
Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
----     ------            ----       ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  fargate-scheduler  Pod not supported on Fargate: volumes not supported: mysql-db not supported because: PVC mysql-db not bound
```

NGINX

```
Events:
Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
----     ------            ----       ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  fargate-scheduler  Pod not supported on Fargate: volumes not supported: admin-panel is of an unsupported volume Type
```

Would really appreciate any help in understanding this problem and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your NGINX and MYSQL pods are requiring `volumeMounts`, you will need a `PersistentVolumeClaim` which is a request for storage from the `PersistentVolume` resource. Your pods can then use the claim as a volume, for more info see [Kubernetes Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

For the longest time EKS Fargate did not support persistent storage until [Aug 17, 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-ek-on-aws-fargate-now-supports-amazon-efs-file-systems/) when the [AWS EFS CSI driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver) was introduced.

You will need to deploy the AWS EFS CSI driver and update your manifests to deploy the PersistentVolume, PersistentVolumeClaim and get your pods to use the claim as a volume. I would suggest starting with the [Amazon EFS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) guide to deploy the CSI driver into your EKS Fargate cluster and update your manifests to match the examples provided [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/multiple_pods/specs).

Comment: man, the guide to deploy the CSI driver into your EKS Fargate cluster is a real sh@t show :(