# Can we add restart time for a pod in statefulset, when the pod is stuck in pending state?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have pvc template creation enabled in statefulset.The pod is created before the pvc binds with the pv. Pod is stuck in pending state for long time showing that the pvc is not bound. Can we alter the time for this pod to restart?
I am using an EKS fargate cluster

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to restart your `Pod`? Do you mean that your `Pod` cannot start unless you delete(recreate) it? `Pod` will not go into `Running` state unless the mounting process is finished.

Comment: My pod is started before the pvc is bound to the pv. So unless i delete the pod its not fetching the latest status of the pvc and running.@DawidKruk

Comment: This answer could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809000/aws-eks-with-fargate-pod-status-pending-due-to-persistentvolumeclaim-not-found