# Helm EKS Fargate + EFS: PVC not bound, but pod restart helps

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

Within one helm chart I deploy a PersistentVolume (EFS):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-{{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.pv.storageClassName }}
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: {{ .Values.pv.volumeHandle | quote }}
  claimRef:
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

And PersistentVolumeClaim for it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.pv.storageClassName }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi  # Required but ignored in case of EFS
  volumeName: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-{{ .Release.Name }}
```

And a pod uses the PVC as usual:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: persistent-storage
    mountPath: /efs

...
  volumes:
    - name: persistent-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

When I do helm install, I have a floating issue: pods continuously in a pending state with the next event:

> Warning  FailedScheduling  56s   fargate-scheduler  Pod not supported on Fargate: volumes not supported: persistent-storage not supported because: PVC someRelease not bound

If I would check state of the PVC, it's in Bound state and after a pod restart it works as expected. It looks like PV is not created yet at the moment when PVC tries to access it, hence the pod can't be created. Should I specify an order for the templates somehow or there is another solution?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did see [this question with similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821328/16739663)?

Comment: Hi @kkopczak, yes, I already have the answer from this link in my code. Everything is ok from that point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: ""
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: {{ .Values.pv.volumeHandle | quote }}
  claimRef:
    name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-{{ .Release.Name }}


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-{{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi  # Required but ignored in case of EFS
```